# What did Allah teach David in Surah Al-Baqarah, Verse 251?

Tags: quran, surat-al-baqarah

[Qur'an 2:251](http://quran.com/2/251) is as follows:

> So they defeated them by permission of Allah , and David killed
>   Goliath, and Allah gave him the kingship and prophethood and taught
>   him from that which He willed. And if it were not for Allah checking
>   [some] people by means of others, the earth would have been corrupted,
>   but Allah is full of bounty to the worlds.

What exactly did Allah taught to David in this verse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's explained in other verses of Quran:

- chanting the psalms (Azzaboor), thus he is example for the perfect reciting that mountains and birds where affected by his recitation.
- Adaptation of iron and making shields
- Judging
- The most important one is he learned about Allah(knowing Allah)

(And Allah knows best).

Comment: Nice and short!